# Can R3 Corda be used for Asset Management?

Tags: assets, corda

I have a usecase in which i need to keep track of assets. User able to create assets, transfer ownership and update various status as time progresses on the assets (active, inactive, in maintenance etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a perfect use case for Corda. Corda holds custodianship of certain assets. Utilizing Corda state, you can tokenize any asset, there are Fixed and Evolvable Token Types. Tokens can be either be fungible or non-fungible.

Check out sample code on IOU where you can issue, transfer and settle an asset: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/a61e2cc9910d7d5de83122bf7d36fd071796a7c3/Advanced/obligation-cordapp

Also check out article Token SDK in Corda: https://www.corda.net/blog/introduction-to-token-sdk-in-corda/